# What's the easiest way to view an iCalendar (.ics) file in my application?

Tags: android, icalendar

I just want to display the data in the .ics file. do I need to parse it or is there some other way to just dump it on the screen?

Comment: There's an ICalendar parser in the [com.android.calendarcommon](http://grepcode.com/search?query=com.android.calendarcommon&n=) in the framework. You should be able to lift this code and use it to parse ICS-files with relative ease.

Answer (score -1):

Looking at the [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar) it appears to be a text file so you could display the raw data.  Otherwise, you would need to create an parser which wouldn't be that difficult.

There are also some possibilities if you [google java ics parser](https://www.google.com/search?aq=f&sugexp=chrome,mod=4&ix=h9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=java%20ics%20parser).

Good luck, hope this helps!